# Is there a good way to freeze an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I have a Javascript module that looks like the following:

```
const data = [
     {
          id: 'do not modify',
          name: 'do not modify'
     },         
     {
          id: 'do not modify 2',
          name: 'do not modify 2'
     }
];

export default data;
```

Is there a clean way I can recursively freeze all objects in an array without explicitly calling `Object.freeze()` on each and every object?  I realize I could just loop through the array and freeze each of them before exporting, but I was curious to know if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can just freeze the array, which itself is an object

Comment: `data.forEach(obj => Object.freeze(obj));` doesn't seem complicated to me.

Comment: @zzzzBov: it's not complicated once you know of the [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) function, which I hadn't until just now (thanks!) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you'd have to do is pass `Object.freeze` to [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
'use strict';
var objs = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 3 }
];

objs.forEach(Object.freeze);
objs[0].a = 4; // Fails due to being frozen
```

Comment: The one thing I would hazard with this is that native methods sometimes change to add additional parameters, and since `forEach` provides 3 parameters to the function, it's a bit safer to wrap it. As `const` was being used in the original example, this can be as simple as passing `obj => Object.freeze(obj)`.

Comment: @zzzzBov Sure but `Object.freeze` only takes one parameter and ignores the rest. But if it's a problem for a certain implementation then using an anonymous function would definitely work.

Comment: It takes one parameter and ignores the rest *for now*. What happens if someone adds a second `deep` parameter? It'd be a largely backwards compatible change that would break your usage.

Comment: I could imagine `Object.freeze` having a boolean 2nd parameter that makes it apply recursively as within the realm of possibility in the future, so I suppose it's a valid point.

Comment: @zzzzBov I get what you're saying and it is a valid concern. But as of right now there's not so much as a proposal in place for adding a boolean parameter. [There is discussion of making a `deepFreeze`](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/my-ecmascript-7-wishlist) method though. Either way, you are right that it's future-proof if you wrap it in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

`data.forEach(Object.freeze)` is the best you can do.

In your case, you might be able to clean up your code like so:

```
const data = [
  unmodifiableObj(0, 'Foo'),
  unmodifiableObj(1, 'Bar')
]

export default data;


function unmodifiableObj(id, name) {
  return Object.freeze({ id, name })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't freeze array with elements inside without calling freeze on every object. Here you can find example of `deep` freeze https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

I'm pasting code from page linked above:

```
obj1 = {
  internal: {}
};

Object.freeze(obj1);
obj1.internal.a = 'aValue';

obj1.internal.a // 'aValue'

// To make obj fully immutable, freeze each object in obj.
// To do so, we use this function.
function deepFreeze(obj) {

  // Retrieve the property names defined on obj
  var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

  // Freeze properties before freezing self
  propNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var prop = obj[name];

    // Freeze prop if it is an object
    if (typeof prop == 'object' && prop !== null)
      deepFreeze(prop);
  });

  // Freeze self (no-op if already frozen)
  return Object.freeze(obj);
}

obj2 = {
  internal: {}
};

deepFreeze(obj2);
obj2.internal.a = 'anotherValue';
obj2.internal.a; // undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated with sample code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Try this:

```
// To make obj fully immutable, freeze each object in obj.
// To do so, we use this function.
function deepFreeze(obj) {

// Retrieve the property names defined on obj
var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

// Freeze properties before freezing self
propNames.forEach(function(name) {
var prop = obj[name];

// Freeze prop if it is an object
if (typeof prop == 'object' && prop !== null)
  deepFreeze(prop);
});

// Freeze self (no-op if already frozen)
return Object.freeze(obj);
}
```

Which will freeze the array itself, as well as any objects it contains.

Comment: `Object.freeze` does not work recursively. It would freeze the array but not the objects in the array.

Comment: ["Note that values that are objects can still be modified, unless they are also frozen."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mkj5z0rg/ well at least the objects in the array return true for `Object.isFrozen()`...

Comment: @GlenDespaux It only specifically works on objects. [Non-objects always return true.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isFrozen#Notes)

Comment: @MikeC I see that now. Thanks for clarification!